# horizontal scrolling element from another source on ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iframe, mobile-safari

I am developing a quick app for mobile safari and it needs to have something like an iframe which embeds a very width document and usr must be able to scroll the content in them.

but if must be based on javascript or some other kind of hack to overcome the iframe scrolling issues.

thanks in advance, hope anyone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used iscroll 4 to accomplish this.

http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

search for the horizontal example.

hope anyone can find this useful